# Detect double tap on home screen in android

Tags: android, service

I want to display a toast when some one double taps the homescreen.I started a service.But do not know how to set up the tap detection part when the service starts.Any help will be appreciated.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Intent i=new Intent(this,TheService.class);
        startService(i);
    }
}


public class TheService extends Service
    {   
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) 
    {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() 
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service created!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service stopped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service started by user.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

         //i want to listen to double tap here
    }

}
```

Comment: What is the relation between the service and the homescreen tapping?

Comment: I want to do something in my app when user double taps on the home screen.service should be used right?excuse me if i am wrong.i am just a beginner.